# Mysql error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Referenced table is 'group' (InnoDB).

It has a 'id' column defined as INT(11), not nullable, auto increment, primary key

Referencing table is 'user (InnoDB)

It has 'group_id' column defined as INT(11), not nullable.

In referencing table already is present an unique index based on 'group_id' column

But whn executing

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `user_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I got an error

> error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I add the db dump

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Check List

1. Is Db InnoDB? Yes
2. Are all tables InnoDB ? Yes
3. Is unique index present on referencing table ? Yes
4. Are referenced and referencing column *exactly* of the same type ? Yes

Question is simple: **why cannot I create this foreign key ?**

UPDATE 1: I tried replacing ON DELETE CASCADE with ON DELETE RESTRICT and nothing changes, also I tried to remove ON DELETE and ON UPDATE an nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed `s` in your table name.

change this

```
   REFERENCES `group` (`id`)
```

to

```
   REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)
```

[**DEmo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58c55)

Comment: 1: Why? 2. I tried with on delete restrict (it's more usefull if I cannot remove non-empty groups), but I got same error 3: Even removing  ON DELETE and ON UPDATE the problem is still here, cannot create